# Selecting elements with a common class but also with differing classes

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a series of elements with differing classes (such as aC, bC bA, etc), but grouped with specific co-classes like "el1" or "el2" or "el3"

Is there a pseudo-selector like `:not()` which accepts classes that can take an initial common class like "el1" and then select the various differing classes within it?

I'd be looking at something like `$(".el1:with(.aC,.rC,.cC,.pC)")`, which would then match against `.el1.aC`, `.el1.rC`, `.el1.cC`, `.el1.pC`, etc; without having to implicitly state the common class, like `$(".el1.aC,.el1.rC,.el1.cC,.el1.pC")`?

I know `:not()`is capable with something like `$(".lCo2:not(.aC,.rC,.cC,.pC)")`, so I'm hopeful there's something on the lines of my `:with()` idea... Is this type of pseudo-selection available in jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to put the differing classes in a subsequent `.filter`:

```js
$(".el1")
  .filter('.aC,.rC,.cC,.pC')
  .css('background-color', 'green');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="el1 aC">text</div>
<div class="el1 rC">text</div>
<div class="el1 pC">text</div>
<div class="el1">text</div>
<div class="el2 aC">text</div>
<div class="el2 aC">text</div>
```